# JAX-RS and Spring Security @PreAuthorize Exception Handling

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jax-rs

I have a setup where we're using JAX-RS / RestEasy along with Spring Security. For the most part, it works just fine, but I'm running into an unexpected hiccup with handling exceptions thrown by `@PreAuthorize`.

We're doing some permission evaluation using SpEL, like so:

```
@POST
@PreAuthorize("@permHandler.canUserUpdate(#request, authentication)")
```

That case will either evaluate to `true`, or throw an exception, `UnauthorizedException`, with some information.

The problem in this case is with handling the `Exception` properly and returning the correct error code to the client.

I have a typical JAX-RS expression mapper set up like so:

```
@Provider
public static class UnauthorizedExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<UnauthorizedException> {
  @Override
  public Response toResponse(UnauthorizedException exception) {
    ...
    return Response.status(403).entity(error).build();
  }
}
```

This handler never gets hit, because `@PreAuthorize` doesn't bubble up my `UnauthorizedException`.  Instead, it isn't quite sure what to do and throws an `IllegalArgumentException` instead.  Mapping the `IllegalArgumentException` to get my 403 response isn't really going to work for obvious reasons.

Is there an accepted way to get this to work with this setup?  Most of the spring security exception handling documentation makes specific references to utilities for spring web or mvc, which is not our case here.

Any help or a nod in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I could be wrong but I thought Spring's method level security, `@PreAuthorize`, throws an `AccessDeniedException`.  You can configure this in your Spring Security config, `HttpSecurity` with the `exceptionHandling()` method.

Comment: That's true when `@PreAuthorize` returns true or false, which is not the case here, we throw an Exception in our authorization utility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to make sure our `Exception` extended `AccessDeniedException` - in that case Spring Security was smart enough to bubble it up rather than throw an `IllegalArgumentException`

Example:
`public class UnauthorizedException extends AccessDeniedException`